# Using excel built-in functions with a variable

Tags: excel, vba, function, trigonometry, degrees

I am an excel noob trying to make a custom excel function that uses degrees while calculating sin of an angle.

```
Public Function SIND(number As Double)
Formula = "SIN(RADIANS(number))"
Formula = Replace(Formula, "number", number)
SIND = Evaluate(Formula)
End Function
```

So far I have this but it doesn't work

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: It just gives an error: #VALUE! :A value used in the formula is of wrong data type. The cell works with regular SIN btw.

Comment: I tested your code and it gave me a number... maybe "it's not working" because of what you are doing with the function? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPdan.png

Comment: It does work with =SIND(2), but when I divide by a number, it doesnt work: =SIND(2/365)

Comment: works for me... https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrAPr.png

Comment: Didn't work for me.. [pic](https://www.hizliresim.com/l6yvnld)

Comment: regional settings? works for me... https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUT0.png

Comment: What does your debug/immediate window show? (like my first 2 screenshots)

Comment: It gives Error 2015 https://www.hizliresim.com/35uplyk

Comment: Maybe the scientific notation? Try changing this: `Formula = Replace(Formula, "number", Round(number, 8))`

Comment: That did not make a difference. https://www.hizliresim.com/2w1be9z

Comment: Your debug is using a comma, not a period. In VBA Code, you have to use a period even if your regional settings are set otherwise.

Comment: I need to probably change some setting somewhere but I can not figure it out. Even this does not work https://www.hizliresim.com/bylhxx0 .

Comment: Use a period, not a comma.

Comment: Using a dot results in a date, and normal SIN works with commas. So, I think I'll ask excel support to change this behaviour.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `Evaluate` to do this? It's not necessary.  It's just over-complicating things.

Comment: No, I just don't know excel. If you have a better way of doing this, I would happily use that one.

Comment: I'm guessing that your settings have Excel using a comma in scientific notation (instead of a period), and Evaluate does not know how to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way:

```
Public Function SIND(degrees As Double) As Double
  Dim Rads As Double
  Rads = WorksheetFunction.Radians(degrees)
  SIND = Sin(Rads)
End Function
```

The main problem with your way is that you were mixing string functions to do math calculations, and that's just not the best method.